# Parsing Json gMaps Api in windows Phone 8 using Serialization

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I Have json file : 
[Google Maps Api - place Json](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=10.8503,106.7673&radius=5000&name=Hospital%20&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAmNV4ha3NUx_u3ykLakrOIlNMu5J3ooBQ)
I want Parsing Json using System.Runtime.Serialization;
I can create 3 class :

```
public class Places
{
    [DataMember(Name = "geometry")]
    public string Geometry
    {
        get;

        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lng")]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "photo")]
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "rating")]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "reference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "types")]
    public string Types { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "vicinity")]
    public string Vicinity { get; set; }
} 
public class AppConstants
{
    public static String baseUri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=";

}
public class PlaceToMap
{
    public GeoCoordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }

}
[DataContract]
public class PlacesList
{
    [DataMember(Name ="results")]
    public List<Places> PlaceList { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
private void updateMap(PlacesList googlePlaceApiRespone)
    {
        int totalRecords = googlePlaceApiRespone.PlaceList.Count();
        try
        {
            ObservableCollection<PlaceToMap> placeToMapObjs = new ObservableCollection<PlaceToMap>();
            for (int index = 0; index < totalRecords; index++)
            {
                placeToMapObjs.Add(new PlaceToMap()
                {
                    Coordinate = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(googlePlaceApiRespone.PlaceList.ElementAt(index).Latitude),
                                    Convert.ToDouble(googlePlaceApiRespone.PlaceList.ElementAt(index).Longitude)),
                    Info = googlePlaceApiRespone.PlaceList.ElementAt(index).Name + Environment.NewLine + googlePlaceApiRespone.PlaceList.ElementAt(index).Vicinity
                });
            }

            ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(myMap);
            var obj = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(MapItemsControl)) as MapItemsControl;

            obj.ItemsSource = placeToMapObjs;
            myMap.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(currentLatitude), Convert.ToDouble(currentLongitude)), 16);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

But can't no show in pushpin.

```
toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}" Content="{Binding Info}"
```